# Log file bloat due to nouveau

Tags: kernel, log, nouveau

Both my kern.log and syslog files have grown to >50Gb and contain a few hundred million lines of:

```
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179453] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 2 [Xorg[1074]] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179469] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179472] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 1 [DRM] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179489] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179490] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 2 [Xorg[1074]] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179507] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179509] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 1 [DRM] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179525] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179527] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 2 [Xorg[1074]] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179543] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179545] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 1 [DRM] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179562] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179564] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 2 [Xorg[1074]] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179581] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179584] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 1 [DRM] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179600] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179602] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 2 [Xorg[1074]] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179619] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
```

I haven't been able to find anything similar on the Google.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem.

I have no clue where it comes from but a reboot solved it for me.

I then made my system more robust by changing the logrotate defaults in `/etc/logrotate.conf` and `/etc/logrotate.d/*` from fixed times to size-dependent.

This way I have a longer history on slow log files and a better prevention against disk overflow from logs gone wild.